# need better method to check swf version to avoid cache (not flash player version)

Tags: caching, version-control, flash, ria

**Why we have this problem**
swf file generated by Flash will be cached by web browser.
there're hundreds of swfs in our project, and we update the project every week.
with every update some swf files might be changed and we need to make sure every user will reload those newest files not cache.
we're having a method by recording versions of all files but that cost too much.
**AND we don't want other unchanged files to be updated by users** so timestamp way doesn't help.

**now comes the question**
any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When calling the files, just use the following pattern: `filename.swf?rand=(a random number here)`, then the SWF will not be cached

Comment: we don't want all files to be updated but only changed ones. i'll add this to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Well is easy, every time you make a new versions like Rapor said you add:

```
filename.swf?version=(new version)
```

Else, if you let the last version,the cache will still be active